# Stripe USD currency with indian user

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have successfully integrated Stripe Payment Gateway Successfully with my Project.
I am having a problem. My Currency is "usd". When an Indian user tries to make a payment and gives the address of India, It gives an error saying Non-INR transactions in India should have shipping/billing address outside India. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports.

When a user from outside India does the payment, It happens successfully.

kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

On further docs reading i have successfully made the payment by providing address and shipping to the payment intent object like this,

I am trying to make a usd payment.

1. U need to have address object while creating a customer
   return stripe.customers.create({
   email: 'test@gmail.com',
   name: 'test',
   source: stripetoken,
   address: {
   line1: '510 Townsend St',
   postal_code: '98140',
   city: 'San Francisco',
   state: 'CA',
   country: 'US', (In your case it's different so sure to change it)
   }
   })
2. Add shipping address object in payment intents like,
   stripe.paymentIntents
   .create({
   amount: '199',
   currency: 'usd',
   // payment_method_types: ['card'],
   off_session: true,
   confirm: true,
   customer: customer.id,
   description: "yesss",
   shipping: {
   name: 'test',
   address: {
   line1: '510 Townsend St',
   postal_code: '98140',
   city: 'San Francisco',
   state: 'CA',
   country: 'US',
   },
   },
   }),

Hope it's works Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Export transactions must be in non-INR currency and domestic transactions must be in INR. There is, currently, no workaround for that.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/supported-payment-methods-currencies-and-businesses-for-stripe-accounts-in-india
https://support.stripe.com/questions/requirements-for-india-export-charges

Comment: That means do i have to make two accounts for both the transactions..?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you say more? You should just be able to set the currency necessary on the payment.

Comment: I have to take payments from both India and outside India. Majority of customers are from outside India. So, i take the currency in USD. Now, for the customers from India, when an Indian user tries to make a payment and gives the address of India, It gives an error saying Non-INR transactions in India should have shipping/billing address outside India. And for customers from outside, it works fine. I need to find the solution for this problem in order to accept payments from India as well as outside India.

Comment: You'll need to determine whether your customer is outside India first then create the payment using USD or INR programmatically. You can't use a single currency for both.

Comment: How do I know whether this user from India or outside of India? Look making external call to ip finder to specify currency is not ideal solution

Comment: @RajaSimon Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: yeah in fact I did. All I have did was use the visitor IP address to figure out where this user comes from. If it's comes from India or other states. If other states then present in usd otherwise inr. And there is no tother way around this.

Comment: Hi @RajaSimon I'm facing the same issue. Can you share the code you used for finding customer country because it would help me a lot. Thanks.