# Got stuck with webhooks in Stripe

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe webhooks to accept payments through my page. I am getting a weird error. When I add my currency as USD, it is asking me to provide an address outside India. That's fine, but when I provide the currency as INR, the address field is not showing on my screen. However, it *is* asking me to provide an address when I submit.

`webhook.ts`

```js
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY ?? '', {
  apiVersion: '2023-10-16',
});

const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

async function handleWebhookEvent(req, res) {
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  const buf = await buffer(req);

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf.toString(), sig, webhookSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Webhook signature verification failed: ${err.message}`);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook signature verification failed: ${err.message}`);
  }

  switch (event.type) {
    case 'checkout.session.completed':
      const session = event.data.object;
      console.log(`Payment successful for session ID: ${session.id}`);


  res.status(200).end();
}

export default handleWebhookEvent;
```

`subscribe.ts`

```js
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY ?? '');

export default async function handler(req:any, res:any) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: [
          {
            price_data: {
              currency: "usd",
              product_data: {
                name: "Sample Product",
              },
              unit_amount: 1000,
            },
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: "payment",
      });

      res.status(200).json({ sessionId: session.id });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Error creating checkout session" });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: as per the law in india any indian customer with indian billing address  is allow to pay in INR only ,only the non indian customer  can pay in other currency (USD in this case). go through [stripe-payment-issue-non-inr-transactions-in-india-should-have-shipping-billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67671137/stripe-payment-issue-non-inr-transactions-in-india-should-have-shipping-billing) and [stripe-usd-currency-with-indian-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65360672/stripe-usd-currency-with-indian-user)

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. But when I choose location as India from the dropdown provided, address field is not showing on the page. Thats my issue

Comment: try adding this `billing_address_collection: 'required',` in the session creates below  `stripe.checkout.sessions.create({ billing_address_collection: 'required'; })`

Comment: That's great. But now I am getting a new error. ```Payment.tsx:30 Error in creating checkout session: IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.```  But I have provided it. When I try to log the id is undefined. help me please!

Comment: check if you are in test key then provide price id from test items and it with production key use production item's price id .

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide me an example? I can't understand clearly as I am a beginner

Comment: if your public key starts like `pk_test_.....` (pk for public key )and secrat key with `sk_test_....` then you are using test configuration or if they are like `pk_live` amd 'sk_live_..' then you are in live mode. you if you creates customer from the test configuration then use test keys and the product id( price id) from that mode else for live use all live configuration,  you should read [stripe-issuing-test-mode-configurations-and-differences-vs-live-mode](https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-issuing-test-mode-configurations-and-differences-vs-live-mode)

Comment: read also [keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys)

Comment: Where I have to provide the price Id and what about the session id in the redirectToCheckout method?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add while this may not be the answer to this particular question. This question was the first result after googling 'stripe webhook hanging after session completed'. @Rainy sidewalks' answer helped me figure out my own problem and fixed it for. This was my code block:

```
success_url: `${getURL()}success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
cancel_url: `${getURL()}paymenterror`,
```

replacing `${getURL()}` with `http://localhost:PORT/` worked for me because `${getURL()}` was returning localhost with https so that's what was causing the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who is reading this the below code may not be the answer to the question but after the discussion as i come to know current problem is with checkout session create.
so understand below block in the context of above discussion

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  customer:stripe_customID,
  billing_address_collection: 'required',
  success_url: 'url to pass the customer on sucess page for example https://exam.....com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  cancel_url: "url to pass the customer to payment failed page if payment cancel due to any reason",
 
 
  line_items: [
    {price: item_Price, quantity: 1},
  ],
  mode: 'payment', //'subscription'// or whatever it is
});
```

return session